# Как получить набор символов заданной категории Unicode?

Tags: c#, linq

Для того, что бы получить заданный набор символов для указанной категории Юникода я создал словарь `charInfo` :

```
// Get all Unicode groups:
Dictionary<UnicodeCategory, IGrouping<UnicodeCategory, string>> charInfo = (
      Enumerable.Range(0, 0x110000)
          .Where  (x => (x < 0x00D800 || x > 0x00DFFF))
          .Select (Char.ConvertFromUtf32)
          .Where  (x => x.Length == 1   )
          .GroupBy(s => Char.GetUnicodeCategory(s, 0))
          .ToDictionary(g => g.Key)
);
```

Когда я извлекаю из словаря категорию `UnicodeCategory.DashPunctuation`:

```
var characters = CharInfo[UnicodeCategory.DashPunctuation]?.ToArray();
```

получается массив `characters` состоящий из 25 символов в то время как исходя [из документации Unicode](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pd/index.htm) в данной категории всего 24 символа.

Я проверил принадлежность символов полученного массива к категории \p{Pd} (Unicode Character Category 'Punctuation, Dash') при помощи тестов и регулярного выражения:

```
Regex.IsMatch(value, @"\p{P}", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

В результате выявлен 1 символ из 25 не относящийся к категории Unicode 'Punctuation, Dash'.

Объясните пожалуйста, почему я получаю 25 символов вместо 24. Где ошибка? Как ее исправить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что вы решили, что последний стандарт Юникода хостится на сайте, который никакого отношения к юникоду не имеет :)

То, что вы считаете «документацией unicode» является документацией версии 5.0 от 2006 года, где в категории [Unicode Dash Characters](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.0.0/ch06.pdf) 24 символа (см. Table 6-3. Unicode Dash Characters).

В [более новых стандартах](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode11.0.0/UnicodeStandard-11.0.pdf) Unicode, начиная с версии [5.2](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.2.0/) от 2009 года уже 25 символов (смотреть ту же таблицу). Соответственно, метод [`Char.GetUnicodeCategory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/360z2b3k(v=vs.110).aspx) основан на более позднем стандарте. (Для .NET 4.6.0 на основе стандарта 6.3, а для 4.6.1 аж 8.0)

Исходя из той же документации, метод `Char.GetUnicodeCategory` может возвращать категорию для символа из предыдущего стандарта по соображениям совместимости. Поэтому, лучше использовать метод [`CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/a91e3zb6(v=vs.110).aspx) который должен всегда возвращать категорию из текущего стандарта юникода для фреймворка.

Comment: Спасибо, заменив метод Char.GetUnicodeCategory на  CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory все заработало. Хотел лишь уточнить нужно ли заменить метод - Char.ConvertFromUtf32 на какой либо более подходящий (по аналогии с Char.GetUnicodeCategory)

Comment: Ну, в документации к методу написано, что несмотря на код (code point), который находится в пределах BMP (`x < 0x00D800 || x > 0x00DFFF`) вы можете получить [невалидный результат](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.convertfromutf32?view=netframework-4.7.2) из-за отсутствия «лингвистической обработки». К сожалению, мне не очень понятно, что тут имеют ввиду и как это может повлиять на вашу задачу